# Relation between Zero dimensional subschemes and saturated ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, projective-schemes

Why is studying zero dimensional subschemes (for simplicity let's say closed subschemes) of $\mathbb{P}^{n}_K$ equivalent to studying saturated homogeneous ideals $I$of $K[x_0,...x_n]$ with krull dimension of $K[x_0,...x_n]/I = 1$ ?

We let $K$ be an algebraically closed field.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: In general closed subschemes of $\mathbb{P}^n$ correspond to saturated homogenous ideals of $k[X_0,...,X_n]$, now as $dim(Proj(A))+1=dim(Spec(A))$ for $A$ a noetherian graded ring you get the claim.

Comment: Thank you @Ahr, for your answer.I now realize that the first part of your answer is Harthshorne chapter $2$, section $5$ ,exercise$5.10$.